# Passing data across view controllers causes a view to load twice in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I would like to pass data in a variable based on a `UITableView` cell selection in one view and then transfer it to a second view (where it will be used).

The data is currently passing successfully, but it causes the second view to load twice (it flashes quickly and then reappears). I cannot debug why this is happening.

Additionally, if I comment out the code for passing the variable, the issue stops so I am confident I am doing something wrong.

In Table View Controller 1, I use:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "passepisode", sender: indexPath)

}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
        let controller = segue.destination as! EpisodeTableViewController
        controller.showNameVariable = TableData[indexPath.row]
    }
}
```

In `EpisodeTableViewController.swift`, I log an empty value for `showNameVariable` that will be updated by the first's view variable here:

```
class EpisodeTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var TableData:Array< String > = Array < String >()
    var TableDataV : [episode] = [episode]()
    var showNameVariable = ""

 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    print(showNameVariable)}
```

This currently logs the text of the former view's cell selection which is ideal.

Before it does that, it flashes the second view controller's table and then reloads for no purpose. I am new to Swift, let me know if I am making an error.

Comment: Is there anything printing in the debugger when the flashing happens?

Comment: @Xcoder: No output in debugger, nothing concerning in console, and no errors in Xcode.

Comment: In the first view controller, there is a `TableData` array other than the one in `EpisodeTableViewController`?

Comment: Don't use capital names for the properties in a class.  What version of Xcode are you using?

Comment: @7stud: xcode 9.2. Is the convention: `episodeTableViewController` you mean?

Comment: @Xcoder: I do have another array in that table but it is named `TableDataV` -- I did not think this would be a problem since the names are different. Am I missing something? Thanks

Comment: No. Class names are capitalized, but the properties shouldn't be: `var tableData`, `var tableDataV`, etc.

Comment: @7stud means that the array names inside the `EpisodeTableViewController` class should be named like `tableDataV` and `tableData`. The class name itself is fine: class names should always start with capital letters.

Comment: ^^^ Then how does this this line work: `controller.showNameVariable = TableData[indexPath.row]`? Is `TableData` a typo?

Comment: Can you post a screen shot of your Connections Inspector(in the storyboard on the right hand side) for the first view controller.

Comment: what TableDataV contains how you are loading value in TableDataV. Post a  sample . And Storyboard screenshot. Make sure you dont have only one segue connected